# Unable to evaluate expressions with overloaded operator in Watch window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I've seen several questions here related to this issue. But they all seem to discuss some STL specific tricks of solving this issue. 
Here's a simple example of the problem. Suppose we use a class, which overloads some operator, say std::vector overloading [] operator:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);

auto x = v[0];
```

When trying to evaluate an expression which calls the overloaded operator, `v[0]` in this case, VC++ shows the following error in the `Watch Window`:

```
v[0] no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

My first guess was that the debugger cannot figure out the type of the argument, so I tried evaluating `v[(size_type)0]` expression and then this `((intvector)v)[(size_type)0]` expressions with the following modification to the code:

```
typedef vector<int> intvector;
intvector v;
```

No luck. I got the same error message again.

It is strange, because when I use the expanded (not sure if it's the correct term here) form of the operator call, then it works: `v.operator[](0)`. And it seems to work universally, not only for STL classes, but also for my own classes which overload [] operator.

In my understanding the two forms `v[0]` and `v.operator[](0)` should be equivalent, but VC++ seems to think differently. Are they really different? Why cannot VC++ debugger evaluate the short form, but has no problem with the "expanded" form? Is there any way around this? I'm very used to just copying a small piece of code and evaluating it in the `Watch Window`.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's debugger expressions don't support overloaded operators if there is a `const` and non-`const` version available. See this [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2t7ahxk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_Operator_Functions).

> The debugger does not support overloaded operators with both const and non-const versions. Overloaded operators with const and non-const versions are used frequently in the Standard Template Library.

Comment: VS fails to show it even when there's only one, non-`const` version in the class. At the same time it works fine for classes implementing both `const` and non-`const` operators, but when the operator is called as a function using the `operator` keyword. That's the main point of the question.